# Hebrew Unicode range not working in a JavaScript regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, internationalization

I am trying to detect Hebrew characters using a regular expression.  From what I have read, this is any character in the Unicode range `0x0590-0x05ff`.

However, the following doesn't work:

```
// Character code \u05e6
var c = String.fromCharCode(parseInt('05e6', 16));

/[\u0590–\u05ff]/.test(c); // false
```

but the following DOES work:

```
// Character code \u05e6
var c = String.fromCharCode(parseInt('05e6', 16));

/[\u0590–\u05e8\u05e9-\u05ff]/.test(c); // true
```

Why?  Why do I have to split the range to `0x0590-0x05e8` plus `0x05e9-0x05ff`?

I tested this in JavaScript in Chrome and in Firefox, and they both have the same behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hyphens are in fact en dashes (U+2013). Real hyphens do the trick.

Comment: That is truly hilarious, thanks.  The lesson I learned here is to never copy-paste code.